# converting nested json into dataframe with a specific output

Tags: python, json, pandas, data-science

Let's say I have some JSON as below

```
response = {
        "totalrecords": 2,
        "data": [
            {
                "stateCd": "U.K",
                "stateName": "uttarakhand",
                "details": {
                    "id": [
                        "2312-k",
                        "2312-k"
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "10-OCT-2019",
                        "11-OCT-2019"
                    ],
                    "icp": [
                        2233,
                        6443
                    ],
                    "icpr": [
                        3.434,
                        23.232
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "stateCd": "U.P",
                "stateName": "uttar pradesh",
                "details": {
                    "id": [
                        "2712-k",
                        "5412-k"
                    ],
                    "date": [
                        "10-OCT-2019",
                        "11-OCT-2019"
                    ],
                    "icp": [
                        2233,
                        6443
                    ],
                    "icpr": [
                        32.434,
                        31.232
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I wanted to convert it into data frame as below

[image]

but while trying to convert it into dataframe using `pandas.json_normalize()`
I am unable to reach my desired output

what I have tried:

```
data_trunc=response['data'] # to extract data from response
pd.json_normalize(data_trunc)
```

[image]

```
pd.json_normalize(data_trunc,record_path=['details','id'],meta=['stateCd','stateName'])
```

[image]

but this don't include `date`, `icp`, `icpr` columns

so I have tried different permutation and combination

```
    pd.json_normalize(data_trunc,record_path=[['details','id'],['date']],meta=['stateCd','stateName'])

pd.json_normalize(data_trunc,record_path=[['details','id'],['details'.'date']],meta=['stateCd','stateName'])
```

but landed up to same error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: Your `response =  {...}` is not actually JSON, it is a Python `dict`, which looks like JSON when formatted like this. (although that's okay here, as `pandas.json_normalize()` does take `dict` input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explode.

```
pd.json_normalize(data_trunc).apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

---

|  | stateCd | stateName | details.id | details.date | details.icp | details.icpr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | U.K | uttarakhand | 2312-k | 10-OCT-2019 | 2233 | 3.434 |
| 0 | U.K | uttarakhand | 2312-k | 11-OCT-2019 | 6443 | 23.232 |
| 1 | U.P | uttar pradesh | 2712-k | 10-OCT-2019 | 2233 | 32.434 |
| 1 | U.P | uttar pradesh | 5412-k | 11-OCT-2019 | 6443 | 31.232 |